# fish shell directory stack

Tags: command-line, fish

In zsh there was an option for pushing each visited directory automatically to the directory stack (`setopt auto_pushd`), represented by `dirs`. I just switched to the fish and recognized that there is no such default option. Also when trying to access `dirs` it is just filled with the current output of `pwd`. Is there a possibility to enable such kind of behavior in fish?

Of course there would be the option to write an own cd function in order to call `pushd` every time you cd into a folder, but as I'm also switching directories just using the path as command that would be not that useful.

So basically can I call a function every time my current working directory has changed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can run a function every time the directory changes, like so:

```
function myfunc --on-variable PWD
    echo Changed!
end
```

However! fish's `cd` is by default a function wrapper that manages a directory stack. (You can see its guts by running `functions cd`.)

You can use `prevd` and `nextd` to move backwards and forwards through your directory history. There is also the shorthand `cd -` to jump to the last directory you were in.

Comment: Okay that sounds good. Yes I know these functions but in my former zsh setup I had the number keys mapped to the last directories in the history

Comment: fish supports mapping keys with `bind`, so you should be able to replicate this. See `man bind` for more.